# I have to explain this function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have to indicate what the function does

```
 void f(char *s, const char *t) {while(*s++ = *t++) ;}
```

I don't understand how the condition in while is evaluated. The condition should return 1 or 0 (False or True) but in this case the content of the (*t) is assigned to (*s). How is that possible?

Can anyone help me please? Thanks =D

Comment: btw, the traditional strcpy indeed copies from the second argument to the first argument; think of an assignment. Also you may want to name the target t and the source s, not vice versa ;-).

Comment: I also believe that most compilers issue a warning here because usually the operator for a condition would be a "==", not a "=", which may be a typo. An additional pair of brackets silences it, indicating intent.

Answer (score 3):

This function iterate on two pointers (`s`and `t`) and copy the value of `*t` into `*s` while the value is evaluated to `true`.

It's probably used to copy strings because strings in C are terminated by `\0` (which is evaluated to false).

It's equivalent to do this:

```c
while(*t)
{
    *s = *t;
    s++;
    t++;
}
*s = *t;
```

Or, like mcleod_ideafix has suggested, to do this:

```c
do
{
    *s = *t;
    s++;
    t++;
}
while (*(t - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer! Can you tell me how can I know that an expression like "\0" is evaluated to false? =D

Comment: The `while` statement is wrong. Should be like this: `while (*(t-1))`. The assignment outside the while is not necessary, unless your `while` statement is rewritten like this: `while (*t)`

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix yep, but I edited and corrected with antoher solution. But your solution don't risks to dereference a memory address which is not in the right segment?

Comment: But how does one know that a expression "\0" is the same as False?

Comment: @GniruT anything other than zero is evaluated to `true` in C and `\0` is the character for the ASCII value zero.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's then better to rewrite it as a do-while instead: `do { *s = *t ; s++ ; t++ ; } while (*(t-1));`

Comment: Your edited answer (based in my second proposal) has a caveat: what if the destintation memory already has a 0 in the position pointed by t? It is necessary first to do the assignment, and then, perform the test (that is what the original code does). That's because I suggest now the do-while approach :)

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Yep, right. But I'll keep the example simple as it's a beginner question. Edit: no problem, if `*t == 0` then you don't enter in the while and you just assign the 0 value to `*s`, no?

Comment: @GniruT, "\0" is true, but '\0' is false. "\0" has type (char*), so it is a valid pointer and not 0. '\0' has type (char) and has value 0 if you cast it to integer.

Comment: @Vadzim I thought that 0 was the representation of true in C...

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator returns the assigned value. So, at the first character equal to zero the function will return (after copying it). This function could be good for example to copy a null terminated string.

In C, any value that is not zero is considered "true".

Comment: No equality involved here ;-)

Comment: Then when the value "\0" is reached in while(). "\0" is evaluated to false?

Comment: just for clarification: in this while loop last value is `'\0'` (not `"\0"`) and `'\0'` is equal to `0`, that means it's false. @GniruT, you can read more about C in this course: [link](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm)

Comment: @GniruT Anything of value zero, which includes the NULL pointer and the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), is evaluated as false (in C, C++ and many other languages).

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*s++ = *t++) ;
```

This while will copy `*t` to `*s` till `*t` becomes **0**. Value of assignment operator is used to check condition, when it reaches to NULL (0) loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an assignment is also an expression (this is different in many other languages but allows for natural chaining of assignments). The value of the expression is the value of the left side after the assignment. That value (here: the character at s before it is incremented) is not zero until the end of the string is reached (and the zero byte there has been copied), terminating the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The way of working can be found in the precedence of operators.

The *operator has the highest priority, when it references to the specific character of the pointer.
After the assignment will come the ++operator which is placed after the variable (right handled) and increases the booth pointers to point to the next characters in the string.

The result of the evaluation which was be stored in the character pointed of s will be in the same time the result of the while condition. The while ends when a '\0' value was be assigned.